# Displaying website image testing vs. production

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently working on updating a .NET Core website which currently has image tags displaying from a URL like:

```
<img src="https://page.website.com/images/image.png">
```

However during testing, I have changed image.png on my development machine.  So if I point to the live URL above, it gives me the old image.  As a result, I have been testing with:

```
<img src="http://localhost/UserInterface/Images/image.png">
```

which properly displays the new image.  My question is, when I commit my code, would `https://page.website.com/images/image.png` properly map to the updated image (included in git add) when the webpage is tested in QA or run in production?  Is this a reasonable assumption to make, or otherwise, how could I test it with the production URL?

These image tags are included in an `.html.cshtml` file used for the UI of an email.

I am happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: No, MVC is not going to rewrite hardcoded, absolute URLs, nor is it going to guess which host and application it's running on. If you're working on `page.website.com`, you could use a relative URL. If not, you have a different problem.

Comment: I don't expect MVC to suddenly use the localhost/UserInterface/... URL.  What I'm saying is I cannot test with the URL used in production since it uses the old image.  If I commit a change to the image and continue to use the original path, even though the image hasn't moved (just been directly replaced), is it reasonable to assume that the production server will use the correct image?  Even though I've been testing with an absolute path for the image when testing an instance of the site running on localhost.

Comment: Why not just use relative pathing: `<img src="images/image.png">` Then it will use whatever image is at that site.

Comment: @DStanley Even if I used relative paths, there are different relative paths `/UserInterface/Images/image.png` vs. `/images/image.png`.  Oddly, even when I tried using the first relative path and when intercepting the email, it didn't work (had the 'x' icon), and the email body showed only the relative path.  It didn't prepend the hostname or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several approaches to test the thing like that:

1. Use relative paths for your inner resources, hence whatever environment you would use, the resource would always be relevant
2. Use templating so that when you build your app, the builder would put relevant source so that you would have different for different environments
3. Use proxies that would forward some URLs to some other URLs so tyhat you would be able to map your "old" source to your "test" source.
4. (not recommended) Redefine some server names in your local machine (for example using hosts file). So that the client would call not the real production server. This might require some reconfiguration of the server that hosts "new" resources since your test server might not accept the name of your prod server.